# Cell deletion animation not kicking in from didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Basically, when you select a specific row, I wand all the rows from the table view to be removed. For this I have the following code:

```
-(void)removeRows:(int)i
{
NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
UITableViewCell *cell = [_table cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];
CGRect newFrame;

if(i%2==0){
    newFrame = cell.frame;
    newFrame.origin.x = -[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
}else{
    newFrame = cell.frame;
    newFrame.origin.x = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
}
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:0
                 animations:^{cell.frame = newFrame;}
                 completion: ^(BOOL finished){
                     if(i == 0){
                         [dataSource removeAllObjects];
                         [_homeScreenView.proustPacks reloadData];
                     }
}];  
}
```

This method is called for each row in reverse order. Now everything works great if i use it for my delete button (which is not part of the tableView), but now I want the same animation and action when the user taps a specific cell, something like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if([(Something*)[dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isWhatIWant]){
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(remove) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.4 target:self selector:@selector(goToNext:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

}
```

Where "goToNext:" pushes the next controller to the navigationController and removePacks is:

```
-(void)remove{
    int aux = _dataSource.count -1;
    for(int i=aux;i>=0;i--){
        [self removeRows:i];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22085713/661749

Basically you need to give all the indexpaths to the remove function and select the animation you want. Don't forget to change your collection as well.

Comment: My method already works and deletes the rows. The problem is i'm not getting my animation on each row.

Comment: It's because you're doing the animation manually. UITableView has a method for this `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`

Comment: Or if you want to remove them individually, just give it the NSArray with one indexpath.